# Firebase Storage cacheControl headers not sent

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I am resizing an image with a cloud function and I eventually upload it to my firebase storage bucket like so:

```
// Upload to GCS
return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
  destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
    metadata: {
      metadata: {
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: 'token',
        cacheControl: "public, max-age=1209600"
      }
    }
});
```

Everything works great, the image is uploaded to the respective bucket, the token works and I can also see the correct metadata `cacheControl: "public, max-age=1209600"` in the storage console.

[image]

Nevertheless, when I load the image in my browser I still get the default firebase cache headers `cache-control: private, max-age=0`.

[image]

I do get a `Status Code: 304` for all downloads after the first one, which is an implicit redirection to a cached resource, but that was already happening by default before I started pushing the cachedControl metadata.

The question is, how can I manage to get the correct cacheControl headers back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after another hour spent on this I figured that the `cacheControl` item has to be inside the first `metadata` object level, not the nested one like `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` does.

Working code:

```
// Upload to GCS
return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
  destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName),
    metadata: {
      cacheControl: "public, max-age=1209600",
      metadata: {
        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: 'token'
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me initially. I had to run my (angular) app in `-prod` and then all of the cache-control headers were realized.